# Grails - error 404 on form submit using g:actionSubmit

Tags: grails, form-submit

I'm new on Grails and I'm having trouble to do a form submit.

Here is AnimaisController:

```
    package jogoanimais

    class AnimaisController {
        def index() { 
            def  animalsTreeObj =  AnimaisTreeMap.list()

            render(view: "show", model: [animalList: animalsTreeObj])       
        }

        def addNode()
        {
            log.info "add node"
            log.info params
        }

    }
```

Here is show.gsp

```
    <g:form controller="animais" action="addNode">  
                <div>Pense em um animal</div>

                <g:textField name="myField" value="${myValue}" />

                <g:actionSubmit value="OK, próximo"  />

                <g:each in="${animalList}" var="row" status="i">
                    <h3> ${row.nodeDescription}, ${row.yesAnswerNode}</h3>
                    <br/>
                </g:each>       
    </g:form>
```

After clicking at the submit button, the URL that is requested is "http://localhost:8080/jogoAnimais/animais/addNode" and I get a 404 error.

I've also tried adding "action" do g:actionSubmit but in this case, Grails requested a addNode.gsp.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Try rendering some sort of response in your addNode() method.

Comment: @mbaird I've tried and no message was shown at log.

Comment: @mbaird that was the solution too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

**GSP:**

Add "action" parameter of g:form and a input type "submit" as shown below:

```
    <g:form controller="animais" action="addNode">  
        <div>Pense em um animal</div>

        <div>
            <label for="questionToUser">Questão:</label>
            <g:textField name="questionToUser" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">    

        <g:each in="${animalList}" var="row" status="i">
            <h3> ${row.nodeDescription}, ${row.yesAnswerNode}</h3>
            <br/>
        </g:each>       
    </g:form>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

As [mbaird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mbaird) has said, my "addNode" mehtod need to return something, as "render 'ok'"